# Change background and font color in Tufte's Book

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tufte

I am using the class `tufte-book`. I'd like to know how can I set the background color and the font color of the front page.

In the book class I have achieved this before using `tikz`, but it seems to not apply here.

A minimal example would be this:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\begin{document}

    \title{This is the title}
    \author{This is the Author}
    \date{Just now}

    \maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to T.S.E., I'm afraid your example isn't very helpful as it doesn't show what you say you did with Tikz or include any color management options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background color for the title page can be set with `\pagecolor` of package `color` or `xcolor`. After the title page, macro `\nopagecolor` turns the page color off.

The text color on the title page is hard-coded to be `darkgray`. Either the title page commands can be patched to use a different color (see macro `\patchcmd` of package `etoolbox`, for example), or the following example redefines the color temporarily:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{yellow}

\begingroup
  \colorlet{darkgray}{red}
    \title{This is the title}
    \author{This is the Author}
    \date{Just now}

    \maketitle
\endgroup

    \newpage

\nopagecolor % or \pagecolor{white}

    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The hard-coded text color is definitely a pain

Answer (score 0):

Here's the tikz version:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\begin{document}

    \title{This is the title}
    \author{This is the Author}
    \date{Just now}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

        \draw[fill=maincolor] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);

        \node[font=\normalfont\fontsize{50}{50}\sffamily\selectfont, color=white, anchor=west] at (0, -10) {Practical Grid};

        \node[font=\normalfont\fontsize{50}{50}\sffamily\selectfont, color=white, anchor=west] at (0, -11.7) {Modelling};

        \node[font=\normalfont\fontsize{50}{50}\sffamily\selectfont, color=white, anchor=west] at (0, -13) {\the\year};

        \node[font=\normalfont\fontsize{35}{35}\sffamily\selectfont \Huge, color=white, anchor=west] at (0, -1) {Santiago Pe\~nate Vera};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```